# Fragment transaction with a FragmentActivity instead of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I would like to add a FragmentActivity in the activity layout. In order to make fragment transactions (such as add, remove, or replace a fragment), the api guides say that I first need to get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity and then add a fragment using the add() method specifying the fragment to add and the view in which to insert it. Ok pretty straightforward so far, but what should I do in the FragmentActivity case?

```
AllEventsFragments events;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ( savedInstanceState == null )
        {  
            events = new AllEventsFragments();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, events,"events");

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

in which AllEventsFragments is defined as follows:

```
public class AllEventsFragments extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
  ...
}
```

Since the add method accepts a Fragment as second argument the error returned is:

> The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, AllEventsFragments, String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to add a FragmentActivity in the activity layout.

You are trying to nest activities. That is not supported via fragment transactions, and what little support there ever was for it has been deprecated for ~2.5 years.

However, you can move much of the `AllEventsFragments` logic into a `Fragment`, which can then be used from both `AllEventsFragments` and wherever else you are trying to use it.

Comment: Ok I've changed AllEventsFragments in a Fragment and it worked. Cheers!